# What is causing these Devise errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to setup [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) like this:

```
$ rails generate devise:install
...
$ rails generate devise User
...
$ rake db:migrate --stack
```

The `rake db:migrate --stack` line causes this error:

```
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Elephant::Application#task called at /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `devise' for User(Table doesn't exist):Class
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1016:in `method_missing'
/Users/ben/rails_projects/elephant/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
/Users/ben/rails_projects/elephant/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:523:in `block in <class:Reference>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in `yield'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in `default'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in `get'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in `to'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:64:in `modules'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/mapping.rb:73:in `strategies'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise.rb:281:in `block in configure_warden!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise.rb:280:in `each_value'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise.rb:280:in `configure_warden!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:7:in `finalize_with_devise!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:128:in `block in reload_routes!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:128:in `reload_routes!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:120:in `block in routes_reloader'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/railtie.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:40:in `initialize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `block in build'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `app'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/ben/rails_projects/elephant/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:216:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

user.rb looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

If I comment out the `devise :database_authenticatable...` line, and run `rake db:migrate --stack`, I get this error:

```
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Elephant::Application#task called at /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:245:in `raise_no_devise_method_error!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:140:in `block in devise_for'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:136:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.5/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:136:in `devise_for'
/Users/ben/rails_projects/elephant/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `instance_exec'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `draw'
/Users/ben/rails_projects/elephant/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `block in reload_routes!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:120:in `block in routes_reloader'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/railtie.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:40:in `initialize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `block in build'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `app'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/ben/rails_projects/elephant/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:216:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

What is causing these errors?

I am running Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: What steps did you take to install devise? Have you migrated the database to the latest version? Also, whats your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: Do you've devise dependency mentioned in your Gemfile ?

Comment: Do you have the line "require 'devise/orm/active_record'" in your config/initializer/devise.rb?

Comment: As a side note, to remove those warnings, be sure to include Rake::DSL in your Rakefile.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason why you ran `rake db:migrate --stack` instead of regular `rake db:migrate`? Also, what's strange is that the first error states that `undefined method 'devise' for User(Table doesn't exist):Class` which suggests that there was a problem loading the model. Do you see the User table in your schema? Also, in your routes file, do you have this line: `devise_for :users`? I'm not sure of this being relevant but I am curious.

Answer (score 2):

Are u using ruby 1.8.7 & rake 0.9~?

TRY THIS:

```
module ::YOUR_APP_NAME
  class Application
      include Rake::DSL
  end
end
```